# Flink Process Function is not returning the data to Sideoutputstream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql

I am trying to validate JSONObject with set of rules if the json matches with set of rules is it will return the matched rule and the JSONObject if not it will return a JSONObject to Sideoutput all this is processed in a ProcessFuntion, i am getting the main output but unable to capture the side output

SideOutput Stream is defined as below

```
public final static OutputTag<org.json.JSONObject> unMatchedJSONSideOutput = new OutputTag<org.json.JSONObject>(
            "unmatched-side-output") {};
```

ProcessFunction is defined as below

```
public class RuleFilter extends ProcessFunction<Tuple2<String,org.json.JSONObject>,Tuple2<String,org.json.JSONObject>> {
@Override
    public void processElement(Tuple2<String, org.json.JSONObject> value,
            ProcessFunction<Tuple2<String, org.json.JSONObject>, Tuple2<String, org.json.JSONObject>>.Context ctx,
            Collector<Tuple2<String, org.json.JSONObject>> out) throws Exception {

        if(this.value.matches((value.f1))) {
        out.collect(new Tuple2<String, org.json.JSONObject>(value.f0,value.f1));
        }else {
            ctx.output(RuleMatching.unMatchedJSONSideOutput,value.f1);
        }
    }
}
```

I am printing main Datastream output as below

```
    DataStream<Tuple2<String, org.json.JSONObject>> matchedJSON =
                            inputSignal.map(new MapFunction<org.json.JSONObject, Tuple2<String, org.json.JSONObject>>() {
                                @Override
                                public Tuple2<String, org.json.JSONObject> map(org.json.JSONObject input) throws Exception {
                                    return new Tuple2<>(value, input);
                                }
                            }).process(new RuleFilter()).print("MatchedJSON=>");

matchedJSON .print("matchedJSON=>");
```

I am printing Sideoutput as below

```
DataStream<org.json.JSONObject> unmatchedJSON =
                        ((SingleOutputStreamOperator<org.json.JSONObject>) matchedJSON.map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<String, org.json.JSONObject>, org.json.JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public org.json.JSONObject map(Tuple2<String, org.json.JSONObject> value) throws Exception {
                                return value.f1;
                            }
                        })).getSideOutput(unMatchedJSONSideOutput );

                unmatchedJSON.print("unmatchedJSON=>");
```

Main Stream is printing output but the sideoutput is not printing for invalid json please help in solving the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```java
DataStream<org.json.JSONObject> unmatchedJSON =
    ((SingleOutputStreamOperator<org.json.JSONObject>) matchedJSON.map(...))
    .getSideOutput(unMatchedJSONSideOutput);
```

You should be calling `getSideOutput` directly on `matchedJSON`, rather than on the result of applying a `MapFunction` to it. Only a `ProcessFunction` can have a side output, and it needs to come directly from the `ProcessFunction`. You tricked the compiler into accepting this by casting the output stream from the map, but the runtime can't do anything meaningful with this.